# why does gdbserver support tracepoint when it is not supported in gdb?

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

i wonder if gdb has some difficulties in supporting tracepoints.

have seen some answers on stack overflow. just mention that "tracepoint facility is currently available only for remote targets."(answered in 2010)

Answer (score 0):

> why does gdbserver support tracepoint when it is not supported in gdb?

Most likely because nobody bothered.

After all, you can *always* use `gdbserver` even for local debugging, so it you want tracepoints, just do that?